# Xinput change "Device Node" property

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, xinput

I have a logitech G9X mouse which implements both a keyboard and mouse interface. The XInput mouse is using the device node for the keyboard `/dev/input/event16` instead of the device node for the mouse `/dev/input/event15`.

Is it possible to change the "Device Node" property to point towards another device node?

I tried:

```
xinput set-prop 16 "Device Node" /dev/input/event15
```

But I got the error:

```
unexpected type for property 'Device Node'
```

Here is the `xinput list-props` for my mouse:

```
Device 'Logitech G9x Laser Mouse':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (270): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (271):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (272):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (273):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (257):    1133, 49254
    Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event16"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (274): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (276):  0
    Axis Labels (277):  "Rel X" (149), "Rel Y" (150), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (448)
    Button Labels (278):    "Button 0" (516), "Button Unknown" (260), "Button Unknown" (260), "Button Wheel Up" (145), "Button Wheel Down" (146), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (147), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (148)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (279): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (281):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (282): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (283): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (284):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (285):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (286):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (287):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (288):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (289):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (290): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (291):  0
```